# How do you make gnome-shell get out of the way in fullscreen apps?

Tags: gnome, virtualbox, interface

I mostly like gnome-shell, and much prefer it to Unity at this point. (In reality, both are greatly lacking in polish.) However, when using fullscreen applications, I notice that the hot corners do not go away.

This is most notable in VirtualBox which I need to run to access windows programs for my job. The gnome-shell notification area covers up the bottom pixel of the entire UI, making the windows taskbar largely useless-- you go to click anything, then need to mouse up a tiny amount for windows to actually see the click. This behavior is particularly annoying. The [Windows] key also fails to be passed to the applications that listen to it, as gnome-shell captures it instead.

I sort of wish I could use gnome-shell with unity's notifications instead, as that's my only real gripe with it. Otherwise, maybe it's a virtualbox issue. Is there a way to get virtualbox to play nice with the new shells? (This might affect Unity as well, I haven't tried it.)

Answer (score 1):

Egads, I've found a partial solution.

It seems that Virtualbox's Mouse Integration is causing these problems. Disabling Mouse Integration and fully capturing the mouse instead clears up the issues for that program. The issue still persists in Chrome for me however. (The virtualbox solution seems to be a cheat, as it disables the native pointer which is probably what gnome-shell is listening for.)